# unable to get TextView value

Tags: android

i have a TextView which shows countdown timer in activity A. and the function for countdown timer is in class B. 
in activity A:

```
TextView tvTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_time);
B a = new B(tvTime);
a.startTimer(20000);
```

and in Class B:

```
public B(TextView tvTime)
{
 this.tvTime = tvTime;
}
```

//Countdown Timer

```
   public void startTimer(int t) {

   Log.d("Timer Value outside cdt", ""+t); 
    timer = new CountDownTimer(t, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            tvTime.setText(""+millisUntilFinished
                    / 1000;);

            Log.d("Timer Value outside cdt", ""+millisUntilFinished
                    / 1000;);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            tvTime.setText("000");
        }

    };
    timer.start();


}
```

and its working fine but when i try to get value of tvTime to save it inSharedPrefs by using following code its not working

```
 public void saveGame(){
    time = tvTime.getText().toString();
    spEdit.putString(SAVED_TIME, time);
    spEdit.commit();
}
```

**Edited:**

By adding 2 debug statements I figure it out that the problem is not in saving the value but the problem is there when i call startTimer() on getting stored value

```
public void getGame(){
startTimer(Integer.valueOf(sp.getString(SAVED_TIME, "0000")));
}
```

after calling this func i can see the result of

```
   Log.d("Timer Value outside cdt", ""+t);
```

but 2nd statement show no result

```
            Log.d("Timer Value outside cdt", ""+millisUntilFinished
                    / 1000;);
```

Comment: your `tvTime` might be out of scope for the method

Comment: where have You used saveGame() ?

Comment: saveGame() is a member of B class and also called inside it @Opiatefuchs

Answer (score 1):

To store the value in SP:

```
 time = tvTime.getText().toString();
Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
      editor.putString("NAME", time );
    editor.commit();
```

To retrieve data from SP:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String name= prefs.getString("NAME", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure your `textview's object is accessible in the particular method`, it might be out of scope for your method. if possible declare your textview object at `class level` so all the class's method can use that

```
public class yourclass 
{
    TextView tvTime;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //--- text view---
        TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_id);
}

public void saveGame(){
    time = tvTime.getText().toString();//now you can use your textview here
    spEdit.putString(SAVED_TIME, time);
    spEdit.commit();
}
}
```

Comment: both startTimer() and saveGame() are in the same class tvTime is working fine in 1st but not in second